# Ricoh Aficio MFP transfer documents from document server

Tags: printer

I need to transfer documents from Ricoh Aficio 5001 document server to Ricoh Aficio 5002.  Is there any quick way of tranferring these onto a USB perhaps and then upload them to 5002 MFP?

Update - There was no way , the 5001 doens't have a USB port unlike 5002. So we were forced to re-scan the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: Ricoh Helpdesk, 4 years.

Sadly there is no way to transfer the documents, short of printing and scanning them into the new MFD. The document server is only really there for people using the machines as a stand-alone copier. If you're printing to it (which I imagine you would, given the size) you should look into setting up Scan-To-Folder on the new machine to prevent future heart-ache.

Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is with the file format convertor type e, your system probably does not have that option installed.

You should be able to enter the IP address of the system in your web browser, then access admin tab, from there you should be able to copy to the new system, Not sure, but it may work.

Art